# SUBSELECT COM COUNT(*) SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

```
SELECT CPF FROM ZPCF WHERE CPF IN
     (SELECT TELEFONE, COUNT(*) FROM ZCPF WHERE  
          GROUP BY TELEFONE HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Preciso que traga o cpf junto com os números de telefone, existem telefones registrados em mesmos cpfs, o subselect funciona o outro diz que tem muitos valores e não achei um jeito de fazer.

Comment: Aqui `... WHERE CPF IN (SELECT TELEFONE, COUNT() ...` não consta o campo `CPF´ na lista de campos do subselect. Creio que seu subselect deva retornar apenas uma lista de CPFs. Estude a cláusula `IN`.

Comment: qual banco de dados você está utilizando e em que versão?

Answer (score 1):

O erro da sua consulta está relacionada com o fato de a subquery está retornando mais de uma coluna. Pois, o filtro da query principal apenas está esperando um conjunto de cpfs.
Para não dá o erro você deveria fazer o seguinte:

```
SELECT CPF FROM ZPCF 
WHERE CPF IN (SELECT CPF FROM ZCPF WHERE
GROUP BY CPF  HAVING COUNT() > 1)
```

Porém, pela descrição do que você espera imaginei que a query correta seria a seguinte:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CPF,TELEFONE FROM ZPCF
```

Essa query vai retornar todos os telefones relacionados com um determinado cpf sem duplicidades.

EX: 
GGG    11111 
AAA    2222 
GGG    11111 
AAA    333333

O retorno da query seria o seguinte:

GGG 11111 
AAA 2222  
AAA 333333